# How to config Docker and Nginx for Wordpress and ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, docker-compose

I have 2 site:

1. Landing page (Wordpress) => product.com (container 1)
2. WebApp (ReactJS) => product.com/app (container 2)

Goal: after clicking on login button from landing page, browser will redirect to app with link WebApp.

How to config Docker and Nginx for both? Thanks

Comment: so what's the question then?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.